# Why is hair getting different densities on arms with same settings (on render)?

Tags: particles, hair

The hair on the left arm looks ok in the viewport, but rare when rendered. It has the same settings as the right arm hair and similar editing with different vertex groups. I added new hair, changed the seed and got similar results. I could add more children, but I thought there must be something wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image: Rendered Image]

Here is an edit with the settings. They are identical for both arms.
[image]

Comment: Please, add screenshots with actual settings